# При скачивании XML файла с сервера ошибка: in _safe_read raise IncompleteRead(data, amt-len(data))

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, http, download

Нужно скачать [файл](https://forward-ua.com/xml_do_diler/price_forward.xml) на ПК.

Написал для этого функцию:

```
def load_XML_forward():
    URL = 'https://forward-ua.com/xml_do_diler/price_forward.xml'
    logo = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
    f = open(path4, "wb")
    f.write(logo)
    f.close()
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py",
> line 614, in _safe_read
> raise IncompleteRead(data, amt-len(data)) http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(65201 bytes read, 3208266
> more expected)

Подскажите способ, как его скачать, либо как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [requests](https://realpython.com/python-requests/):

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import requests  #  pip install requests


def download_text_file(url, filename=None):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()
    if filename is None:
        filename = os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
         file.write(r.text)


url = 'https://forward-ua.com/xml_do_diler/price_forward.xml'
    
download_text_file(url, "/tmp/prices.xml")
```